# Cancel a $('form').submit() call in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm in trouble when I use form submit event in jQuery.

#### Markups

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <a id="btn_submit">Submit</a>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

#### Event listener

```
function valid() { return false; }

$('form').submit(function() {
    if(!valid()) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then, when I click that `<input type="submit" />` it do trigger that event, and can cancel the submit event.

---

But when I trigger the form submit on the `.btn_submit` tag, return false cannot cancel the submit.

#### Failure of cancel

```
$('#btn_submit').click(function() {
    $('form').submit();
    // $('form').trigger('submit');
    // document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

---

So, now the question is, if I must use an `a.btn_submit` to trigger the submit of form, and I want to cancel that submit in case.

1. How should I trigger?
2. How should I cancel?

Please help!

---

I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/69wcduv5/2/.

But it seemed cannot submit in jsfiddle.

---

#### My final solution (a bit dirty)

I can create a submit input inside the form, then trigger a click on it. Then remove it.

If I trigger the submit in this way, I acts exactly the same as I expected:

1. **The validation code inside the `$('form').submit(function() {});` don't have to change.**
2. If the form has something like `<input type="text" required />`, it can do well.
3. I can style well on that anchor. Not the f**king `<input type="submit" />`

Thank you all for your patient, best regards.

And hoping for a clean better solution.

Comment: Why is the href on the link? You don't need it and it looks incorrect.

Comment: @MarkKadlec Nothing to do with the problem, I've removed that. Thanks!

Comment: @epascarello What do you exact mean? Do you mean it is not possible, and I shouldn't do that? Or something else?

Comment: Why are you using JS to handle the click on an `<input type="submit">`? Does your real code do more than simply trigger the form submit?

Comment: @nnnnnn Just because if I click a submit input, I can be canceled, but if I trigger by script, it cannot cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the submit in this way, the most close to my intention:

```
$.fn.natural_submit = function() {
    if($(this).is('form')) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var $input_submit = $('<input type="submit" />').hide().appendTo($form);
        $input_submit.trigger('click');
        $input_submit.remove();
    }
}

$('#btn_submit').click(function() {
    $('form').natural_submit();
});
```

Comment: Yes, should work. Can be simplified to one line - `$('<input type="submit" />').hide().appendTo($(this).filter('form')).trigger('click').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.btn_submit").click(function(){
  if($('form').valid())
  {
     $('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: What I want to do is to validate inside the `$('form').submit(function() {})` handler. Your answer doesn't do that.

Comment: How you can check `if(!valid())` ?

Comment: It's just a example to show that problem, assume that to be `false` here.

Comment: If form is valid then you can submit form using `$('form').submit();` other wise it do not submit form.

Comment: But I don't what to valid that form everywhere I call the trigger, I want the validation to be written only once! I know your code can work, but not my want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    if(!valid()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are doing wrong. I absolutely sure, that my way will correctly prevent form submit. Your `valid()` is broken.

Comment: Why would this work when `return false;` didn't? In a jQuery-based event handler `return false` ends up doing `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I understand now what you are trying to achieve, so please ignore what I wrote before.

`formElement.submit()` and its jQuery equivalent very deliberately do not trigger an onsumbit event. Othwise there is the potential for infinite recursion.

Therefore, you *cannot* execute `$('form').submit();` and hope for an onsubmit handler to intercept.

Your best bet is probably your "dirty" idea. Namely to trigger a click on a (hidden) `type="submit"` button.

Answer (score 1):

Seems weird to use a link to submit a form, but your problem is you are not cancelling the click action on the anchor.

```
$('.btn_submit').on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: The essential point is based on two reason: 1. I use an anchor to trigger is just to show that I may trigger the `submit()` anywhere in case, maybe more than once. 2. If I do the validation on the anchor click event, I have to write that validation code every where with much redundancy, I want to prevent that.

Comment: I also know a pretty dirty solution, just to make a hidden `<input type="submit" />`, and any action to submit is just trigger a click on that input. But you know, it is a little bit dirty. But what I want is to reduce the repeat of validation code.

Comment: I found a solution by myself, please have a look, it shows my intention.